# How to find id and set attribute in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

Tried to set attribute value from html content by fs but not working. How to do it using javascript or nodejs.

public/index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>My First Heading</h1>
<p>My first paragraph.</p>
<div>
<a href="#" id="reset">Link</a>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

app.js:

```
 var fs = require('fs');
 fs.readFile('./public/index.html', { encoding: 'utf-8' }, function(err, html) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                } else {

                html.find('#reset').setAttribute("href", "http://localhost:4200/home/");
   }
   });
```

Comment: `document.getElementById("reset").href = "http://localhost:4200/home/";`

Comment: @ScottMarcus — Where does `document` come from?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `cheerio` like @Quentin mentioned. 
OR You can add a placeholder for the `href` attribute in the html file.

```
<div id="reset" href="%%RESET_PLACEHOLDER%%">content</div>
```

And then you can replace the placeholder using `string.replace()` method.

```
const fs = require('fs');

const path = __dirname + '/public/index.html'; //file path

fs.readFile(path, {encoding: 'utf8'}, (err, data) => {
  let dataToWrite = data.replace(/%%RESET_PLACEHOLDER%%/g, 'hrefVal');
  fs.writeFile(path, dataToWrite, (err) => {
    console.log('file written');
  });
});
```

Comment: How to decript the data: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-sha3s1

Comment: Which data you need to decrypt?

Comment: test@gmail.com  need to decript

Comment: var ciphertext = "1d80462608388a6a58648c049dff14b9"; //test@gmail.com

Comment: You have answer?

Comment: Seems like you are using the wrong ciphertext. `test@gmail.com` when encrypted using `secret key 123` as the secret key produces `U2FsdGVkX183P7Ezy6xC8J417SoRHuVSwz2Lnt7zC2I=`.

Comment: I've modified it here: 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-dnmwyp?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: I have encripted the mail in nodejs like this: 
 encrypt() {
    var cipher = CryptoJS.createCipher('aes-256-cbc', 'd6f3Efeq');
    var crypted = cipher.update("test@gmail.com", 'utf8', 'hex')
    crypted += cipher.final('hex');
    return crypted;
}

Comment: So i am trying to decript in angular 8

Answer (score 0):

When you read a file you get a **string** (or a buffer if you use different options).

Strings are not a DOM so you can't search it for elements.

You need to use something that can parse it into a DOM such as *libxmljs* or *cheerio*. Then you can use that to manipulate it and serialize it back to a string of HTML.

Comment: const newHtml = cheerio.load(html); 
                    newHtml.find("reset").setAttribute("href", "http://localhost:4200/home/");

Comment: @PappaS — Well yes. That isn't how cheerio works. https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio#-selector-context-root-

Comment: Not working: const $ = cheerio.load(html); 
                    $('a .reset').attr('href', 'http://www.google.com');

Comment: Well you don't have any elements with `class="reset"` that are *descendants* of `a` elements. The selector you had in the code in the question was fine. Why did you change it?

Comment: Class or id no problem..But i want to set attr value

Comment: You have any answer?